# What needed to be change for Paypal when updating http to https?

Tags: paypal

I'm in the mid of updating my server from http to https, even do a simple test on paypal redirect and it seems to work redirecting it back to https. However I want to make sure i got it right, is there any settings i needed to update in paypal?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PayPal Standard with PDT / Auto-Return setup in PayPal then you may need to change the values there for your Return URL.  Also, if you have IPN configured in PayPal you may want to update that.  Otherwise you should be good to go.

Side note, it would be good to go ahead and setup rules on your server, too, so that any traffic that comes to http:// gets 301 redirected to https://.  This can be done easily with an htaccess file if you're running on Apache.